# SIGTRAP on delete[] with small arrays

Tags: c++

A weird SIGTRAP error appears in a C++ OpenGL program of mine.
First, a float array with the new[] operator is created like so:

```cpp
std::vector<ObjFace> faces = readObjFile("sphere.obj");
vertexBufferSize = faces.size() * 24;
auto* vertexBuffer = new GLfloat[vertexBufferSize];
```

Then, the array is filled like this:

```cpp
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j{ 0 }; j < 4; ++j) {
            vertexBuffer[i*24 + j*8] = faces[i].corners[j][0];
            vertexBuffer[i*24 + j*8 + 1] = faces[i].corners[j][1];
            vertexBuffer[i*24 + j*8 + 2] = faces[i].corners[j][2];
            vertexBuffer[i*24 + j*8 + 3] = 1.0f;
            vertexBuffer[i*24 + j*8 + 4] = (faces[i].normals[j][0] + 1) / 2;
            vertexBuffer[i*24 + j*8 + 5] = (faces[i].normals[j][1] + 1) / 2;
            vertexBuffer[i*24 + j*8 + 6] = (faces[i].normals[j][2] + 1) / 2;
            vertexBuffer[i*24 + j*8 + 7] = 1.0f;
        }
    }
```

And it is then used with the `glBufferData` Macro and deleted afterwards:

```cpp
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferSize * sizeof(GLfloat), vertexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

delete[] vertexBuffer;
vertexBuffer = nullptr;
```

For some reason the program will sometimes crash on a SIGTRAP error (debug mode) or with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374) (regular execution). I also made sure that `vertexBuffer` is not a nullpointer.

This problem only occurrs if the array size is relatively small. For bigger sizes, it works without a problem. To get it working with smaller sizes, I must not use `new[]` and `delete[]` - but then it will crash on bigger arrays because they take up too much space. Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: What if instead do `std::unique_ptr<GLfloat[]> vertexBuffer(new GLfloat[vertexBufferSize]);`  and `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferSize * sizeof(GLfloat), vertexBuffer.get(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);` and drop the need for `delete[]` and `vertexBuffer = nullptr` - same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write 32 floats per face but you seem to have thought you were only writing 24. You're allocating 24 floats per face and skipping forward 24 floats to get to the next face, but you're actually writing 32 floats per face, because you're writing 8 floats per vertex and 4 vertices per face. So you always end up writing an extra 8 floats after the end of the array.

Comment: Thanks man! If you're working with some code for a long time, you sometimes overlook the easy stuff - especially when you have some weird behaviour. Your answer just solved a long time of debugging and reviewing for me - so thank you a lot!